# Getting empty value from array

Tags: php, arrays, key, var-dump

I have the following code and $totalDonations should output 1500.

```
<?php
    $donations = $wpdb->get_results("
      SELECT amount
      FROM wp_fullstripe_payments
    ");
?>

<?php $totalDonations = array_sum($donations); ?>

<?php echo $totalDonations; ?>
```

I get 0 from $totalDonations.

Here is the var_dump for $donations:

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2108 (1) { ["amount"]=> string(3) "500" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#2107 (1) { ["amount"]=> string(4) "1000" } }
```

This doesn't work either:

```
<?php echo $donations[0]; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the result as an stdClass

Try

```
<?php 
     $totalDonations;
     foreach ($donation as $donations){
       totalDonations += $donation->amount;
     } 
?>
```

Check out this link : http://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/08/20/php-stdclass-storing-data-object-instead-array/